# Comparing two files in java

Tags: java, file, while-loop

I am trying to compare two .txt files (i.e their contents), but when I execute this code my application goes into an infinite loop.  Why?

```
public int compareFile(String fILE_ONE2, String fILE_TWO2)throws Exception 
{

File f1 = new File(fILE_ONE2); //OUTFILE
File f2 = new File(fILE_TWO2); //INPUT

FileReader fR1 = new FileReader(f1);
FileReader fR2 = new FileReader(f2);

BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(fR1);
BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(fR2);

String line1 = null;
String line2 = null;
int flag=1;
while ((flag==1) &&((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null)&&((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null)) 
{
    if (!line1.equalsIgnoreCase(line2))  
        flag=0;
    else 
        flag=1;   
}
reader1.close();
reader2.close();
return flag;


}
```

Comment: Insert println statements inside your loop and see what it's doing.

Comment: You should break; while loop when you reach first no-equal line or you will get the result of the last line compare.

Comment: I dnt think any infinite loop exist in the code.

Comment: Looks good to me, what does the debugger say?

Comment: You can remove `else flag=1;`.  It's not needed.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting infinite loop? From the code it doesn't look like.

Comment: How large are your files? If your files have thousands or millions of lines, probably, your program is taking too long but, as other people has said, the code looks good, there's no infinite loop.

Comment: @Marco, `break` is not needed because of `flag==1`.

Comment: Do keep in mind that if you compare "binary" (non-text) files with this algorithm there may be no newline characters in the files and you may end up reading the entire file into heap before even beginning the actual compare.

Comment: @pepuch right, but it can also be used to improve this so ugly while (for me, of course.). (My comment wasn't to try to fix the problem, sorry for that.)

Comment: first check the file size (file.length()) are same or not . if its not same any way your files are not going to match..

Answer (score 1):

I converted your code into a main program.  There is no infinite loop in this code.

I am assuming you are comparing 2 text files of a small-ish size.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Diff {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        File f1 = new File(args[0]);// OUTFILE
        File f2 = new File(args[1]);// INPUT

        FileReader fR1 = new FileReader(f1);
        FileReader fR2 = new FileReader(f2);

        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(fR1);
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(fR2);

        String line1 = null;
        String line2 = null;
        int flag = 1;
        while ((flag == 1) && ((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null)
                && ((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null)) {
            if (!line1.equalsIgnoreCase(line2))
                flag = 0;
        }
        reader1.close();
        reader2.close();
        System.out.println("Flag " + flag);
    }
}
```

I ran it on 2 small different text files.  This is the output.

```
javac Diff.java && java Diff a.txt b.txt
Flag 0
```

If you think you have an infinite loop, the issue might be elsewhere.

Comment: @rick, why do you think you have an infinite loop?  Perhaps the issue is somewhere else?  You can use the same strategy here to test a bit of code in a java main line application.  (JUnit/TestNG is better, but  this will work also).

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Hi @JohnKugelman, I actually spent some time to test with different files.  Also the OP wanted to know why there was an infinite loop and I think I have answered the question.  I have also presented a strategy for the OP to check code by running it like this.

Comment: Generally speaking, "I can't reproduce this" should be a comment. Your answer doesn't really say *why* the OP's program doesn't work, you just say you can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Most likely, OP is calling `compareFile()` inside a loop that never ends.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good, no infinite loops. You can remove irrespective check in the code and can update the code as below:

```
int flag=1;
while (((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null)&&((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null)) 
{
    if (!line1.equalsIgnoreCase(line2)) 
    { 
        flag=0; 
        break;
    }
}
```

As the return type of the method is integer than it will return `0` if different and `1` if equal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming text file inputs, an alternative implementation to the `while` loop:

```
while (true) // Continue while there are equal lines
{
    line1 = reader1.readLine();
    line2 = reader2.readLine();

    if (line1 == null) // End of file 1
    {
        return (line2 == null ? 1 : 0); // Equal only if file 2 also ended
    }
    else if (line2 == null)
    {
        return 0; // File 2 ended before file 1, so not equal 
    }
    else if (!line1.equalsIgnoreCase(line2)) // Non-null and different lines
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Non-null and equal lines, continue until the input is exhausted
}
```

The first `else if` is not necessary, but it is included for clarity purposes. Otherwise, the above code could be simplified to:

```
while (true) // Continue while there are equal lines
{
    line1 = reader1.readLine();
    line2 = reader2.readLine();

    if (line1 == null) // End of file 1
    {
        return (line2 == null ? 1 : 0); // Equal only if file 2 also ended
    }

    if (!line1.equalsIgnoreCase(line2)) // Different lines, or end of file 2
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The loop should be placed in a `try/finally` block, to assure that the readers are closed.

Answer (score 0):

Above method by Jess will fail if file2 is same as file1 but has an extra line at the end.

This should work.

```
public boolean compareTwoFiles(String file1Path, String file2Path)
            throws IOException {

    File file1 = new File(file1Path);
    File file2 = new File(file2Path);

    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));

    String thisLine = null;
    String thatLine = null;

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    while ((thisLine = br1.readLine()) != null) {
        list1.add(thisLine);
    }
    while ((thatLine = br2.readLine()) != null) {
        list2.add(thatLine);
    }

    br1.close();
    br2.close();

    return list1.equals(list2);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if you use java8, the code below to compare file contents

```
public boolean compareTwoFiles(String file1Path, String file2Path){
      Path p1 = Paths.get(file1Path);
      Path p1 = Paths.get(file1Path);

try{
        List<String> listF1 = Files.readAllLines(p1);
    List<String> listF2 = Files.readAllLines(p2);
    return listF1.containsAll(listF2);

        }catch(IOException ie) {
            ie.getMessage();
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is incredibly ineffective - reads the whole files into memory. Also, incorrect - containsAll() does not check if the order is the same.