# How to compare two java.io.File Programmatically

Tags: java, android

Is there any ways to compare two files in Android?

> For example: I am having two files under same folder, which are same.
>   They are **same**(also in size), but their namea are like
>   `myFileA.pdf` and `myFileB.pdf`. So how can I identify that they are
>   same or not.

What already I had tried:

- **`compareTo()`** method: Tried `myFileA.compare(myFileB)`, but that's giving some weird values like -1, -2, etc. I think those values are files' **PATH** dependent.
- **`myFile.length()`**: but in **some** rare cases (very rare cases), two different files can have same size, so I think this is not a proper way.

> **NOTE**: I told that files are under **same** folder for just example, they can be anywhere like `myFileA.pdf` can be in
>   `NewFolder1` and `myFileB.pdf` can be in `NewFolder2`.

Comment: maybe calculate the hashvalues for both and compare them?

Comment: "Tried myFileA.compare(myFileB), but that's giving some weird values like -1, -2, etc." have you checked the JavaDocs of `compare()`?

Comment: did that, but they gives different values @Rotwang

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379059/determine-if-two-files-store-the-same-content http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764299/comparing-two-files-in-java http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90147/checking-for-differences-between-two-large-files and many other resources can be found using a Google search on `compare two file contents in java`.

Comment: Calculate hash is a good choice maybe not the optimal when the two files are big and they differ in content since the first byte.

Comment: @Meet "did that, but they gives different values" are you sure you want to compare duplicate files and not "similar" ones?

Comment: @Sufian I want to compare different files with same content like fileA.txt and copyOfFileA.txt

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for that, I will look for that.

Answer (score 4):

Some times ago I've written an utility to compare the content of two stream in an efficient way: stop the comparison when the first difference is found.
Here is the code that I think it's quite self explicable:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class FileComparator implements Comparator<File> {

    @Override
    public int compare(File file1, File file2) {

        // one or both null
        if (file1 == file2) {
            return 0;
        } else if (file1 == null && file2 != null) {
            return -1;
        } else if (file1 != null && file2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        if (file1.isDirectory() || file2.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to compare directory content");
        }

        // not same size
        if (file1.length() < file2.length()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (file1.length() > file2.length()) {
            return 1;
        }

        try {
            return compareContent(file1, file2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

    }

    private int bufferSize(long fileLength) {
        int multiple = (int) (fileLength / 1024);
        if (multiple <= 1) {
            return 1024;
        } else if (multiple <= 8) {
            return 1024 * 2;
        } else if (multiple <= 16) {
            return 1024 * 4;
        } else if (multiple <= 32) {
            return 1024 * 8;
        } else if (multiple <= 64) {
            return 1024 * 16;
        } else {
            return 1024 * 64;
        }
    }

    private int compareContent(File file1, File file2) throws IOException {

        final int BUFFER_SIZE = bufferSize(file1.length());

        // check content
        try (BufferedInputStream is1 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file1), BUFFER_SIZE); BufferedInputStream is2 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file2), BUFFER_SIZE);) {

            byte[] b1 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            byte[] b2 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

            int read1 = -1;
            int read2 = -1;
            int read = -1;

            do {
                read1 = is1.read(b1);
                read2 = is2.read(b2);

                if (read1 < read2) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (read1 > read2) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    // read1 is equals to read2
                    read = read1;
                }

                if (read >= 0) {
                    if (read != BUFFER_SIZE) {
                        // clear the buffer not filled from the read
                        Arrays.fill(b1, read, BUFFER_SIZE, (byte) 0);
                        Arrays.fill(b2, read, BUFFER_SIZE, (byte) 0);
                    }
                    // compare the content of the two buffers
                    if (!Arrays.equals(b1, b2)) {
                        return new String(b1).compareTo(new String(b2));
                    }
                }
            } while (read >= 0);

            // no difference found
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two files:

```
public static boolean compareFiles(File file1, File file2) {
        byte[] buffer1 = new byte[1024];
        byte[] buffer2 = new byte[1024];
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
            while (fileInputStream1.read(buffer1) != -1) {
                if (fileInputStream2.read(buffer2) != -1 && !Arrays.equals(buffer1, buffer2))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Of course, before you do that, you have to compare file sizes. Only if it matches, then compare the contents.