# need a method to read two files and out put the difference using a scanner class

Tags: java, file, class, compare

This is what I have so far. I'm not sure where to go from here. I need a method to output the difference in two files

```
    package JwolfrumCh6;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class JwolfrumCh6 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  
    {
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter File one Name");
            String file1 = console.nextLine();
            Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File(file1));

            System.out.print("Enter File two Name");
            String file2 = console.nextLine();
            Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File(file2));
        }
        public static void compareFiles(Scanner input1, Scanner input2) {

            while(input1.hasNextLine() || input2.hasNextLine()) {

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by output using Scanner class? Scanner is used to read input. If you want to compare two files you can check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764299/comparing-two-files-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Call the static method in main and implement below logic in your compareFiles method.

1. Read all lines of file 1 to an ArrayList
2. Read all lines of file 2 to another ArrayList
3. Use removeAll method of ArrayList as shown below to get the differences in each of these files.

   ```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class FML {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
       Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter File one Name");
       String file1 = console.nextLine();
       Scanner input1 = new Scanner(new File(file1));

       System.out.print("Enter File two Name");
       String file2 = console.nextLine();
       Scanner input2 = new Scanner(new File(file2));
       compareFiles(input1, input2);
   }

   public static void compareFiles(Scanner input1, Scanner input2) {
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
       while (input1.hasNextLine()) {
           list1.add(input1.nextLine());
       }
       while (input2.hasNext()) {
           list2.add(input2.nextLine());
       }
       List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<String>(list1);
       tmpList.removeAll(list2);

       System.out.println("content from file1 which is different from file2");
       for(int i=0;i<tmpList.size();i++){
           System.out.println(tmpList.get(i)); 
       }

       System.out.println("content from file2 which is different from file2");

       tmpList = list2;
       tmpList.removeAll(list1);
       for(int i=0;i<tmpList.size();i++){
           System.out.println(tmpList.get(i)); 
       }

   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks in my Java class we haven't made it into working with arrays. That is the next chapter. your post helped me greatly