# Compare the content of two csv files in java

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to compare the content of two csv files. I have the csv file test1.csv and test2.csv. The content from both should be the same.. if not , then I want to transfer the difference into a .txt file. If every thing is equal, everything is correct.

I just created two test csv files with columns and rows with content

The first column is a primary key of the respective table. I want to compare it by the identificator

```
test1.csv
1,Max,New York
2,David,Jersey
```

```
test2.csv
1,Max,California
2,David,Jersey
```

The Output here in the .txt should be the row `"1,Max,New York"`

I just have no code. And I am happy about every adivce and hint I can get. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the first digit unique ? How do you distinguish two lines you should compare ?

Comment: Why not `"1,Max,California"`?

Comment: From your description, you would not need to parse the csv file. Just read every line from both files and then compare them using equals. if they mismatch you can dump those lines to a new file.

Comment: @AmitD you are only correct if you presume the two files have equal size.

Comment: @deHaar youre right. I could output both lines which are not equal

Comment: @Lia The reason why you are recieving downvotes is because the question is not formulated in a way that the readers can provide you with clear solution. If you notice my answer I use 2 presumptions. You need to specify exactly what you want to achieve. Or the chance for the question to get closed is high.

Comment: From your description, you can solve this problema just use linux comand with comm, for example: comm -3 test1.csv  test3.csv > diff.text

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov yes I see it. I am sorry, I always trying to be clear. I edit the question

Comment: @Lia from the question it is not clear if you need a line by line comparison or if you have an identificator for a record. Ffrom what I see you have a digit infront of each record. My presumption is you use record identificator.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov thx for your answer. I need it by an identificator. The first column is the primary key of the table test1 and test2

Comment: @Lia how big files will you be dealing with ? Any hint on size ?

Comment: @Alexandar Petrov I am just testing now.. not very big like 100 lines for example..can I iterate line by line? like till the end of the rows?? but I am not really sure how to do this.. with the condition to prove if there are all lines equal..

Comment: You have not presented a very clear question, nor have you included any code to explain what your issue is and you are actually admitting you don't even have any code. This makes the question unclear and way to broad and it should be closed. See the Help Center for how to write a good question.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov I mean it is a good solution to print the primary key column which is not equal in the txtfile as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest the simplest approach will be compare two file contents using an online tool which will give you an idea about what is different. You can refer the following link.

https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

If you want, you can use tools like winmerge for which you need to download.

If you want to achieve in java, refer below the two links.

https://javaconceptoftheday.com/compare-two-text-files-in-java/

[Comparing two files in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764299/comparing-two-files-in-java)

Comment: Thank you. But the second link.. is that the same for xlsx oder csv files ? Because of the rows and columns

Comment: I have provided you the link so that you can learn and implement. Second link is for text file, it means you can read both the csv files, read each line and you can compare.

Answer (score 0):

If you have record identifier at the front. In that case you need to sort the one or both files if they are not already sorted and start reading line by line from file one and searching equal Id in the second file. There are various strategies for optimization here sorting being the most generic. Since the second one is sorted esentialy the search can be very fast if you use an index.

An example naive solution that will work with small to medium files would be to read the second file in memory and arrange it in a TreeMap(this will implicitly sort it) where the key is the ID and the value is the line.

Then you strat reading the source file line by line and test against the treemap if the line is equal or not. If not you decide what to do with the two lines.